# Function to imitate Java's ArrayList.remove(o)

Tags: java, javascript, arraylist

How can I implement a function that does the same thing as `ArrayList.remove(o)`?

The closest thing I have is

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(o) {
    var index = this.indexOf(o);
    if(index == -1) {
        return;
    }
    return this.splice(index, index);
}
```

However it throws an error on the second line, claiming `indexOf(o)` doesn't exist. (`cannot find function indexOf()`)

Comment: How are you calling the method?

Comment: The most basic way I try to call it is `var x = ["apples", "oranges", "lemons", "potatoes"]; x.remove("potatoes"); println(x);` (println exists because I'm using rhino within Java)

Comment: As well as the above question, what browser are you using? IE doesn't have `Array.prototype.indexOf` in older versions.

Comment: `Array.prototype.indexOf` is not supported by IE7 and below.

Comment: Your implementation works just fine in Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/V8aLE/

Comment: Really? Does it work with instances of objects as well? It fails for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "instances of objects?"

Comment: If you're doing that operation a lot on lists of any appreciable size, you should probably be using a different data structure.

Comment: For example, like a prototype function.  I do not know JavaScript vocabulary very well.

Comment: Indeed. What you're asking is still unclear. How about asking with code instead of prose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Array.prototype.indexOf` is not supported by IE7 and below. So you would need to *shim* that method aswell before, like

```
Array.prototype.indexOf = Array.prototype.indexOf || function( search ) {
    for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++) {
        if( this[ i ] === search ) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
};
```

<sup>(simplified example)</sup>.

Furthermore, your call to `.splice()` is wrong, second argument is the length of elements you want to remove and it should be `1`.

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(o) {
    var index = this.indexOf(o);
    if(~index) {
        this.splice(index, 1);
    }
};
```

Comment: what is `if(~index` is it a bitwise op?

Comment: @ajax333221 `~` performs a bitwise negation. Bitwise NOTing any integer `x` evaluates to `-(x + 1)`. Examples" `~0 = -1`, `~2 = -3`, `~-5 = 4`. While it's a clever trick to use here, it makes the code more confusing to understand and maintain.

Comment: Thanks!  That remove function works perfectly; I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @ajax333221: MattBall explained it technically. Its actually just a shortcut for `if( index > -1 )`

Comment: I'm not sure it's always going to be faster, however.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL: well, actually I'm more sick of always writting the annoying line `foo > -1`.. so its really meant as shortcut.

Comment: @ajax333221: most of the times this is a cruicial failure. You need to compare against `> -1`, because `0` is an index position mostly.

Comment: @jAndy `x >= 0` is the same as `x > -1`, `∀ x ∈ ℤ`

Answer (score 1):

Another idea would be to use and "associative array", aka object literal with name value pairs and use the delete operator which works in all modern browsers.

```
var arr = {'x': somval, 'y': someval2 ...}
delete arr.x;
```